# Genre for models in DJango

Tags: python, django, model

I am creating a site with Django, and I encounter a problem with the administration site.

When I create a new model, I can assign a `verbose_name` for the singular and plural in the meta class, but I don't find any option that allows me to assign what *gender* that model is, that is, whether it is *feminine (female)* or *masculine (male)*.

For example, I have the city model, which in Spanish would be **Ciudad** and would be *feminine*. Then when on the admin site I add a new record, the legend **Se añadió con éxito el ciudad** appears, when the right thing would be **Se añadió con éxito la ciudad**.

I know this could be a translation issue,

but I suppose something should indicate to the translations that the model should put **el** or **la** as the case may be.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Post some code, dont be subjective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I can offer is to overwrite the method that generates the message.
First we overwrite the method that generates that message: `response_add`

```
from django.contrib import admin, messages
class CityView(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_add(self, request, obj):
        #you can put your own code here to generate a message
        msg = 'Custom message'
        self.message_user(request, msg, messages.SUCCESS)
        return self.response_post_save_add(request, obj)
```

Then we indicate that when we create a city use the custom view we create.
For this in the file where we registered the models on the admin page we put the following:

```
from .admin_custom import CityView # assuming the file is called admin_custom.py
admin.site.register(City, CityView)
```

**Edit**
For add all at once you can do the next

```py
from .admin_custom import CityView
from .models import *
models = (City, Class1, Class2)
admin.site.register(models, CityView)
```

Comment: Hi.
I have tried the option you suggest and it seems good to me, but you know if there is any way to overwrite this method on all models at once.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.
I have solved the problem using the response received and making some adaptations. Since I already had admin.ModelAdmin classes created, I created a main class that overwrites the response_add method, and I have inherited my ModelAdmin classes from it. Here the code in case it serves someone else.

```
# admin_custom.py
from django.contrib import admin, messages
class ModelView(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_add(self, request, obj):
        msg = 'Registro añadido satisfactoriamente' # Generic message for male and female models
        self.message_user(request, msg, messages.SUCCESS)
        return self.response_post_save_add(request, obj)

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin, messages
from .models import Pais, Ciudad, ...
from .admin_custom import ModelView
@admin.register(Pais) 
class PaisAdmin(ModelView):
    inlines = [CiudadesInline]

@admin.register(Ciudad) 
class CiudadAdmin(ModelView):
    list_display = ('nombre', 'pais')
    list_filter = ('pais',)
    inlines = [TeatrosInline, ArtistasInline]

...
```